# MS SQL пересечение диапазонов дат

Tags: sql

Как вывести сотрудников у которых пересекся отпуск?

```
Справочник сотрудников
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Name VARCHAR(255)
)
 
INSERT INTO Employee (ID, Code, Name)
VALUES (1, 'E01', 'Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich'),
  (2, 'E02', 'Petrov Petr Petrovich'),
  (3, 'E03', 'Sidorov Sidr Sidorovich'),
  (4,'E04','Fedorov Fedor Fedorovich'),
  (5,'E05','Mihailov Mihail Mihailovich')
 
 
-- Отпуска сотрудников
CREATE TABLE Vacation (
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ID_Employee INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee(ID),
  DateBegin DATE NOT NULL,
  DateEnd DATE NOT NULL
)
 
INSERT INTO Vacation (ID_Employee, DateBegin, DateEnd)
VALUES (1, '2019-08-10', '2019-09-01')
  ,(1, '2019-12-29', '2020-01-14')
  ,(2, '2019-05-01', '2019-05-15')
  ,(4,'2020-01-09','2020-02-05')
  ,(5,'2020-06-12','2020-07-14')
```

Я смог выбрать только по ID отпускам, как вывести имена из 1 таблицы у которых я нашел отпуска из 2 таблицы?

```
SELECT v1.ID_Employee, v2.ID_Employee
FROM Vacation v1, Vacation v2
WHERE v1.DateBegin < v2.DateBegin AND v2.DateBegin < v1.DateEnd
```

Comment: У меня получается выбирать по 1 человеку
{
SELECT Name 
FROM Employee
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT v1.ID_Employee
FROM Vacation v1, Vacation v2
WHERE v1.DateBegin < v2.DateBegin AND v2.DateBegin < v1.DateEnd)}

Answer (score 0):

Ну например

```sql
SELECT e1.Name, e2.Name
FROM Vacation v1
JOIN Vacation v2 ON v1.DateBegin < v2.DateEnd
                AND v2.DateBegin < v1.DateEnd
                AND v1.ID_Employee < v2.ID_Employee
JOIN Employee e1 ON v1.ID_Employee = e1.ID
JOIN Employee e2 ON v2.ID_Employee = e2.ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f969f033083faf4554d3ec20dd2b7300

Comment: Получилось как-то так. Как можно улучшить? Не костыльный ли запрос? 


SELECT Name
FROM Employee 
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT v1.ID_Employee
FROM Vacation v1, Vacation v2
WHERE v1.DateBegin < v2.DateBegin AND v2.DateBegin < v1.DateEnd)
OR ID IN (
SELECT v2.ID_Employee
FROM Vacation v1, Vacation v2
WHERE v1.DateBegin < v2.DateBegin AND v2.DateBegin < v1.DateEnd)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, ID
FROM Employee 
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT v1.ID_Employee
FROM Vacation v1, Vacation v2
WHERE v1.DateBegin < v2.DateBegin AND v2.DateBegin < v1.DateEnd)
OR ID IN (
SELECT v2.ID_Employee
FROM Vacation v1, Vacation v2
WHERE v1.DateBegin < v2.DateBegin AND v2.DateBegin < v1.DateEnd)
```

Comment: WHERE IN is slow in most cases. Use WHERE EXISTS or JOIN.